# Index on Column with Very Few Distinct Values

Tags: index, postgresql-performance

I have to query a table of stock prices that includes a column 'split_coefficient' where split_coeffieint is almost always 1.0, but very occasionally is something other than that: 2.0, 0.5, etc.

I have tried adding a partial index on split_coefficient where 'split_coefficient != 1.0', but postgres does not use it in its query plan.  Also tried, just a normal index on split_coeffient, which was not used either.

I typically query 'select * from fmvs where commodity_id == <SOME_ID> AND date BETWEEN  and  AND split_coefficient <> 1.0'.

I have an index on commodity_id, and date.  What is the best way to index on split_coeficient to speed up the query.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 1):

You stated in your question

> I typically query 'select * from fmvs where commodity_id == <SOME_ID> AND date BETWEEN and AND split_coefficient <> 1.0'.

and

> I have an index on commodity_id, and date

You need a compound index with all threee columns in this order

```
CREATE INDEX covering_index ON fmvs USING btree(commodity_id,date,split_coefficient);
```

That way your query explain plan should perform an index scan on the three columns. The scan will be narrowed down to a `date` range scan on `commodity_id` and look got  those `split_coefficient` values before reaching out to the table for row data.

Having an individual index on `commodity_id` and another individual index on `date` will not suffice.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  That looks like it did the trick.